# Trouble understanding the remainder for an alternating series

Tags: sequences-and-series

Lets say we have a series $a_n(-1)^n$

- lets assume we are finding the remainder of the series

Looking at the series $\sum_1^{\infty}a_n(-1)^n$ I know that if the series converges to S that the nth partial sum is $S_n$

- Cool, but the nth partial sum does not give us the sum of the whole series

I understand that there is a remainder which can be calculated from $ S = S_n + R_n$.

$S-S_n = R_n$

$S_n$ = $\sum_{1}^{n}a_n(-1)^n$

$R_n = S-\sum_{1}^{n}a_n(-1)^n$

$R_n$ = $\sum_{n+1}^{\infty}a_n(-1)^n$

An explanation I found on a website says that if the series converges to S by the alternating series test ( lets assume it does), then the remainder Rn can be estimated as follows for all n ≥ N: $|R_n| ≤ a_{n_+1}$

So by this definition the size of the error is at MOST $a_{n_+1}$. But that does not make sense to me because the error is defined as $\sum_{n+1}^{\infty}a_n(-1)^n$, so it looks like the error should be at LEAST $a_{n_+1}$ because that is the first term and there are an infinite number of terms after that which are decreasing but should still add value to the remainder or am I just interpreting the explanation wrong?

Also can someone explain what n ≥ N means?

Thanks

Comment: You missed an important condition of the alternating series test: $|R_n| ≤ a_{n+1}$ holds if the sequence $(a_n)$ is *decreasing.*

Comment: If all the terms were positive, then yes, the remainder would be at least $a_{n+1}$. But since the terms decrease and alternate signs, you get $|R_n| \leq |a_{n+1}|$. The key thing here is that the partial sums alternate over-estimating and under-estimating the final limit $S$, while getting closer to $S$ in absolute value.

Comment: Look more carefully (on any book or web page on series) at that statement *and its proof*.

Comment: Oh so like if $a_{n+1}$ was $x_1$ and the series is decreasing then the absolute value of $x_1$ would have to be bigger than the absolute value $x_2$ and since one or the other will be negative the first term would always be the biggest for $|R_n|$ that you can get right?